# SDL2 Texture Manipulation Tutorial Can't Execute - Lazy Foo http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/40_texture_manipulation/index.php

Tags: c++, textures, sdl, surface

I have been playing with  SDL2 Texture Manipulation Tutorial Problem - Lazy Foo [SDL2 Lazy Foo Texture Manipulation Tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/40_texture_manipulation/index.php)

but it doesn't even run.
Apparently, the cause of segmentation fault is something to do with the surface format used to create the texture or something.

Crash point 1:

```
SDL_Surface* formattedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface( loadedSurface, SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow )->format, NULL );
```

Crash point 2:

```
//Map colors
Uint32 colorKey = SDL_MapRGB( SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow )->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF );
Uint32 transparent = SDL_MapRGBA( SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow )->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00 );
```

Can anyone help on it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind found it!

Crash point 1 needs to be replaced with

```
formattedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat( loadedSurface, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, NULL );
```

Crash point 2 needs to be replaced with:

```
Uint32 colorKey = SDL_MapRGB( formattedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF );
Uint32 transparent = SDL_MapRGBA( formattedSurface->format, 0XFF, 0XFF, 0XFF, 0xFF );
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about line 119?

```
//Convert surface to display format
SDL_Surface* formattedSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface( loadedSurface, SDL_GetWindowSurface( gWindow )->format, NULL );
```

You shouldn't need to manually specify the pixel format like in your first workaround, but to be fair, Lazy didn't call SDL_ConvertSurface properly, and I'm wondering if that's what causes an issue for you.

The proper syntax, as shown in the [SDL Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurface), is:

```
SDL_Surface* SDL_ConvertSurface(SDL_Surface*           src,
                                const SDL_PixelFormat* fmt,
                                Uint32                 flags)
```

Also note that the third argument, the flags, "[...] are unused and should be set to 0; this is a leftover from SDL 1.2's API".

I was warned about that and some other repeated errors by using the -Weffc++ compiler flag, then checked the wiki to see the options for flags. It's not a bad idea to use it to prevent (unwitting) bad habits.

You should probably make sure you're on a relatively new version of your toolchain, and use the compiler flags for c++11. I found those steps necessary for at least one earlier Lazy Foo SDL2 tutorial, with regards to new string functions.

Try and run a debugger and see what exactly is causing the crash. Watching gWindow from the beginning and stepping through should be insightful. FWIW, I didn't have any issues with this one. You can also get weird crashes if you're missing a DLL or other file the executable expects.

I'd be curious to know your OS specs, toolchain and version, SDL2 and libs versions, and also to see any build errors/warnings and console output.